# Inline Block With Return Type

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Is it possible in Objective-C to create a block inline and use its return type? For example, can I create a block that returns a `BOOL`, have it be inline, and use its return type for an assignment.

```
BOOL b = <inline block that returns BOOL> { // unsure of the syntax / legality of this
    return YES; // will be more logic in here, that is why I want to use a block.
};
```

I am having trouble with the block syntax, and am unsure if a block can be created inline. I have checked the following resources with no avail.

- [Block Cheat Sheet](http://twobitlabs.com/2012/12/objective-c-ios-blocks-cheat-sheet/)
- [Gosh Darn Block Syntax](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com)
- And of Course, [The Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1)

Thankyou for your time and patience if this happens to be impossible, or very easy.

Comment: Are you planning on using b for anything OUTSIDE of the block, or is all the logic that will use the returned bool value going to happen inside the block?

Comment: I am simply using the block for its return value. In the block there will be logic that will determine whether or not it returns `YES` or `NO`, and this will be assigned to `b`. So no, `b` will not be used in the block. @Mike

Comment: I personally wouldn't use a block at all - just put that logic in a function and call the function that returns a bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you would need to do use the following:

```
BOOL b = ^(){ return YES; }();
```

This actually creates the block and then calls it. It's not nice to read though, so you may as well just do something like this:

```
BOOL b = NO;
{
    // Other stuff, will be local
    b = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A different way to achieve that result is a ["compound statement expression"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

```
BOOL b = ({
    BOOL result;
    // other local variables and stuff, computing "result"
    result; // The last expression is the value of this compound statement expression. 
});
```

This is a GCC extension to the C language (and understood by Clang as well). It looks
*similar* to a block, but is something different.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a good reason for this, but you can indeed do it. Just put the function call parentheses after the block

```
BOOL b = ^{
    return YES;
}();
```

This is really identical to declaring and using it separately, then inlining it.

```
BOOL (^returnB)() = ^{
    return YES;
};
BOOL b = returnB();
```

Answer (score 1):

You **don't need to create a Block** to do this. If you're not assigning the Block itself to a variable to reuse later, then it is pointless. Just do the necessary calculations and put the result into `b`.

```
BOOL b = ^BOOL(NSString * s, int n){
    unichar c = [s characterAtIndex:n];
    return c == "w";
}(myString, 5);
```

should just be

```
unichar c = [myString characterAtIndex:5];
BOOL b = c == "w";
```

If you're worried about scoping for some reason, use a compound statement (enclosing the lines in braces) or a [statement expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037571/how-is-this-form-of-scoping-called).